# SQL command that decreases value in table by 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a table called `Orders(Id,Number,ProductName)`.

I need a SQL command that decreases the value in the `Number` column by 1. The `Number` column has type `nvchar(50)`.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type - that's what they're there for, after all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Number = Number - 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/207da/1)

If some of the values are non-numeric in your Number column, you can use isnumeric to check:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET Number = Number - 1
WHERE IsNumeric(Number) = 1
```

[More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/094d1/1)

Comment: I"m sorry but i forgot the column type

Comment: @user2302416 Still works as long as the value in the `NVARCHAR` is numeric. To note though is that the update above updates _all orders in the entire table_, not just a specific one.

Comment: I don't understand why you would change to _adding_ one if you use the `IsNumeric()` check.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
Update Orders
    set Number = cast(cast((case when isnumeric(Number) = 1 then Number end) as int
                          ) - 1 as nvarchar(50)
                     )
```

Just because a column is called `Number`, I don't believe that "numbers" will always be in it unless I check.  If it really is a number, than declare it as some numeric type.

Comment: Why not just `UPDATE Orders SET Number = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Number) = 1 THEN Number-1 ELSE Number END`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  . . . You can do that.  I just get nervous when mixing types. I've had a lot of painful experiences with implicit conversions, so I now try to be explicit whenever I can.

Comment: Probably wise, wasn't a complaint just more of a "better ask just in case this is a bad idea" :)